# jQuery regexp table search not searching in all columns, only first column

Tags: jquery, regex, search, html-table

I've finally got this to work and I can filter by searching by name. I cannot, however, get it to filter by searching for a value in any column. For example, I want to be able to type in 'gmail' and to show only those records that have gmail in any of the table cells in that row. Even if I add `class="name"` to every `td`, they are not included in the search.

HTML:

```
<input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search table by name">

    <table caption="Data type 1" sortable id="name_table"><col width="20%"><col width="20%"><col width="15%"><col width="20%"><col width="25%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Job No.</th><th class="no-sort">Phone</th><th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">End of records</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="name">John Smith</td><td>123 Fake Street</td><td>Job 117</td><td>0405788996</td><td>john@company.co</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="name">Jane Smyth</td><td>1234 False Road</td><td>Job 118</td><td>0405788555</td><td>jane@hercompany.co</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="name">Alexey Fadeev</td><td>12 Dubio Lane</td><td>Job 119</td><td>0405788966</td><td>af@anothercompany.co</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    // Table Search
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
      var regex = new RegExp($('#search').val(), "i");
      var rows = $('table tbody tr');
      rows.each(function (index) {
        name = $(this).children(".name").html()
        if (name.search(regex) != -1) {
          $(this).show();
        } else {
          $(this).hide();
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

I would love to be able to add a class to every column or cell within `<tbody>` I want to include in the search. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `.html()` method, it return the HTML of the first element in the stack. May i suggest you to change this line :

```
name = $(this).children(".name").html();
```

to this :

```
name = $(this).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not including all the text in the tr use

```
$(this).html(); or $(this).text();
```

instead of

```
name = $(this).children(".name").html();
```